# How to pass knockout.js value to ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

We have an MVC project that displays a table. The table is populated with a knockout.js array. I'd like to be able to pass a value to a Actionlink() like below but "knockoutVar" isn't recognized.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<!-- ko foreach: $root.myFileList -->
  <tr>
   <td data-bind="text: Document"></td>
   <td> @Html.ActionLink("click me", "mymethod", "mycontroller", new {id = knockoutVar }, null)      </td>
```

Comment: You are confusing Server side and client side code. The `@Html.ActionLink` will be rendered on the server, well before knockout will be able to pass anything to it on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the data-bind attr directly on a hyperlink tag:

```
<td><a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("mymethod", "mycontroller")?id=' + knockoutVar() }">click me</a></td>
```

Edit: Not sure why downvoted? This is tested code and will create an link pointing to: http://url/mycontroller/mymethod?id=1001

Comment: Not sure why this got down voted. Seems like a very reasonable solution to me. I would move it into the viewmodel but it explains the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer seems right to me as well, the only other way I can see what is something feasible, is that you actually don't want to trigger a server-request but stay in the js-viewmodel context, then you can simply add a data-bind attribute like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("clickme", "action", "controller", new { data_bind = "click: (item) => alert(item.id)" })
```